# Confirm or cancel all rows of gridview when paging is true using radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm displaying data in gridview where user will be confirming or cancelling records by selecting radiobutton. Radiobuttonlist contains two radiobutton confirm or cancel and is populated with each record in gridview[image: Like this]
But pagination is true for the gridview and i m not able to confirm/cancel all records at a time only the records which are shown page wise are confirmed/cancelled.

i tried this solution but it is not working after clicking confirmAll button, gridview gets hidden.

```
protected void BtnCanclAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.AllowPaging = false;
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.DataSource = BindGrid();//getting data from database
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.DataBind();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdGSMCheckerDetails.Rows)
    {
        RadioButtonList rb = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("Radio1");
        //if (rb.SelectedItem != null)
        rb.SelectedValue = "0";
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Now Press Update Button to Cancel All.');", true);
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.AllowPaging = true;
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.DataSource = BindGrid();
    grdGSMCheckerDetails.DataBind();
}
```

this is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdGSMCheckerDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" ShowHeader="True" CellPadding="5"
                ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnSorting="grdGSMCheckerDetails_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="grdGSMCheckerDetails_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdGSMCheckerDetails_RowDataBound">
                <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview" BackColor="#7779AF" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm/Cancel">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio1" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Confirm" Selected="False" />
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Cancel" />
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="White" />
                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SCRIP_CODE" SortExpression="SCRIP_CODE" HeaderText="Scrip Code" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="11px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" HeaderStyle-Width="8900px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="12px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LISTED_STATUS" SortExpression="LISTED_STATUS" HeaderText="Listed Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="11px" ItemStyle-Font-Size="12px" HeaderStyle-Width="8900px">
                        <HeaderStyle Font-Names="verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif" Font-Size="12px" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="12px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>

                <PagerStyle BackColor="#016091" Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="White" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#016091" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle Height="2px" BackColor="#016091" Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="14px" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

i want confirm/cancel radiobutton to get selected for all records in the grid on click of confirmAll/cancelAll button

Comment: Why not set on the data source and bind it back ?

Comment: tried but then to not working.

Comment: You are saying you have changed the value in the data source and bind in to grid view ? Can you show that code ?

Comment: No i have not changed the datasource, before binding i m attaching datasource like this         grdGSMCheckerDetails.DataSource = BindGrid(); on both the stages i.e removing paging and again allowing

Answer (score 0):

First, if it's a paged grid why do you want to select the radio buttons which user don't even see ? Just select the buttons in current page and set a flag to confirm all and read that on update button click

put a hidden field in the page

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfConfirmAll" value="false" >
```

On confirm all button click make the hidden field true and select visible radio buttons using JavaScript (not server side )

On update button click check for hfConfirmAll if true update all records otherwise update only selected records

Comment: but if user wants to confirm all records once then what should i do? all the radio button should get selected

Comment: That's what I told when confirm all click set the hidden field confirm all to true, if not set it to false